# Using Counters in foreach, animate

Tags: foreach, animate

I´m trying to create an animation of rectangles approximating the area below 
a curve (x^2). I´ve tried to use a counter to specify the lenght of the 
rectangles but Latex won`t let me use \divide or \multiply on counters in \foreach.

Is there a way to do something like

```
\frac{1}{\then}
```

to use in

```
\foreach \x in {0,1\divide\then,...,1}
```

What I´ve tried so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
%%%


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shadows,trees, decorations.markings, 
positioning, patterns, plotmarks,         
matrix,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,shapes.symbols,chains, 3D, 
calc}


\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=15mm, bottom=5mm }

\definecolor{mred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}

 %  
 %
\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{01}

%

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,poster = first, controls]{1}
\whiledo{\then < 4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
                \draw[->] (-0.1,0) -- (1,0)node[above right]{$x$};
                \draw[->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1)node[above right]{$y$};
                \draw[style=help lines, step=0.2] (-0.01,-0.01) grid (1,1);
                \draw[domain=-0.1:1, smooth, very thick] plot(\x,{\x*\x});
                \foreach \x/\xtext in {0.2,0.4,0.6/0.6,0.8/0.8,1/1}
                                            \draw[shift={(\x,0)},scale=1/6] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)node[below] {\small{$\xtext$}};
                \foreach \y/\ytext in {0.2,0.4,0.6/0.6,0.8/0.8,1/1}
                                            \draw[shift={(0,\y)},scale=1/6] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)node[left] {\small{$\ytext$}};

                \foreach \x in {0,0.\then,...,1} 
                                        \draw[thick, mred] (\x,0) rectangle (\x+1\divide\then,\x^2);        
                \node[below] at (0.5,-0.1) {$n=$\then};                 
            \end{tikzpicture}   
\stepcounter{n}
\ifthenelse{\then < 4}{\newframe}
{\end{animateinline}\relax
}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an animation solution, approximating the area under the curve. Please cut and paste the code and compile to show that approximation. `animate` package is required.

First, a `App` macro taking 2 arguments is defined. #1=number of frame and the last frame is also the total frame of `\multiframe{total frame}`.  As to #2, it is designed such that 1/#2 is the horizontal/base length of approximating rectangles. For example, #2=2 means the rectangle length=0.5cm, so #2=32 would means the length is 0.03125cm.

[image]

[image]
Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shadows,trees, decorations.markings, 
%positioning, patterns, plotmarks,         
%matrix,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,shapes.symbols,chains, 3D, 
%calc}

\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=15mm, bottom=5mm }

\definecolor{mred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}

\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{01}
%
\newcommand{\App}[2]{
\whiledo{\value{n}=#1 \and \icount=#1}{
 \stepcounter{n}
 \foreach \y in {#2}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{1/\y}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\evalue}{1-\step}
      \foreach \x in {0,\step,...,\evalue}{
      \draw[thick, mred] (\x,0) rectangle (\x+\step,\x^2);        
      \node[below] at (0.5,-0.1) {$n=\step$};}}} 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,poster = first, controls]{1}
\multiframe{6}{icount=1+1}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
      \draw[->] (-0.1,0) -- (1,0)node[above right]{$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1)node[above right]{$y$};
      \draw[style=help lines, step=0.2] (-0.01,-0.01) grid (1,1);
      \draw[domain=-0.1:1, smooth, very thick] plot(\x,{\x*\x});
      \foreach \x/\xtext in {0.2,0.4,0.6/0.6,0.8/0.8,1/1}{
      \draw[shift={(\x,0)},scale=1/6] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)node[below] {\small{$\xtext$}};}
      \foreach \y/\ytext in {0.2,0.4,0.6/0.6,0.8/0.8,1/1}{
      \draw[shift={(0,\y)},scale=1/6] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)node[left] {\small{$\ytext$}};}

     \App{1}{2}
     \App{2}{4}
     \App{3}{5}
     \App{4}{8}
     \App{5}{16}
     \App{6}{32}   % multiframe=6
\end{tikzpicture}  
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key problem is that you are missing the `\xtext` and `\ytext` parts in the main `\foreach` cycles. I have extended those parts from `0.2,0.4` to `0.2/0.2,0.4/0.4`. In this case, you could use only one variable per cycle as `\xtext` and `\ytext` only duplicate their `\x` and `\y` counterparts.

The next problem is the use of `\divide` itself. We use regular slash for division (`/`). Well, I believe that there should probably be rather `\x+0.\then` instead of `\x+0/\then`. Please, you decide that!

I enclose an example of how far I have got in your source code and two previews of the animation.

```
%! *latex tikz-animate.tex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shadows,trees, decorations.markings, 
  positioning, patterns, plotmarks, matrix, decorations.pathmorphing,
  backgrounds,fit,shapes.symbols,chains, 3D, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external} \tikzexternalize
\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=15mm, bottom=5mm }
\definecolor{mred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{01}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{1}
\whiledo{\then < 4}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
                \draw[->] (-0.1,0) -- (1,0)node[above right]{$x$};
                \draw[->] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1)node[above right]{$y$};
                \draw[style=help lines, step=0.2] (-0.01,-0.01) grid (1,1);
                \draw[domain=-0.1:1, smooth, very thick] plot(\x,{\x*\x});
                \foreach \x/\xtext in {0.2/0.2,0.4/0.4,0.6/0.6,0.8/0.8,1/1}
                                            \draw[shift={(\x,0)}, scale=1/6] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node [below] {\small{$\xtext$}};
                \foreach \y/\ytext in {0.2/0.2,0.4/0.4,0.6/0.6,0.8/0.8,1/1}
                                            \draw[shift={(0,\y)}, scale=1/6] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node [left] {\small{$\ytext$}};
                \foreach \x in {0,0.\then,...,1} 
                                        \draw[thick, mred] (\x,0) rectangle (\x+0.\then, \x^2); % or 0/\then?
                \node[below] at (0.5,-0.1) {$n=$\then};                 
            \end{tikzpicture}   
\stepcounter{n}
\ifthenelse{\then < 4}{\newframe}
{\end{animateinline}\relax}
}% End of \whiledo...
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe 1]
[image: mwe 2]