# Loop incompatible with animateinline newframe?

Tags: beamer, loops, animate

**EDIT: Marmot has provided me with alternative solution, for which I'm very grateful. Question however remains because I'd like to learn what was wrong with my approach.**

I want to make a presentation with beamer, on one frame (beamer frame) I want to have tikz animation with over 30 frames (of animation). I don't want to type out each frame (of animation) manually, so I attempted to use \loop to create frames (of animation).

After removing all excess code, I reduced conflicting part to this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\newcount\spiniter
\spiniter=1
\begin{animateinline}[loop,controls]{10}
Text 0
\loop
\newframe
Text \the\spiniter
\advance \spiniter 1
\ifnum \spiniter<10
\repeat
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which fails to compile with `! Improper \prevdepth` error.

Note: sample does not use tikz, as I wanted to isolate conflict as much as possible, code sample is supposed to animate "Text x", starting with x=0 and ending with x=9.

For comparison, this manually prepared command set works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{animate}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,controls]{10}
Text 0
\newframe
Text 1
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

constantly switching between "Text 0" and "Text 1" as desired (ignore awful positioning of buttons, this is not relevant).

<s>Could someone suggest some way to achieve what I want to do? All other drawing commands are already written and parametrised with integers.</s>

EDIT: Great thanks to marmot, who in comments pointed me towards question containing alternative solution. However if anyone knows, I'd like to learn what was wrong with my approach.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! I am not sure I understand what you want to do. `animate` has its own means to do loops. Replace your loop with `\multiframe{10}{icount=1+1}{Text \icount}` to see what I mean. Does this give you what you want?

Comment: @marmot Well, in actual presentation I want to have png image+tikz drawing animated together. I "glued" them together with \tabular and "encapsulated" that in animateinline, separating with \newframes, but doing that for multiple frames is a lot of pointless work. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168140/121799?

Comment: @marmot Solution from question you linked worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear. Something that, according to my experience, often helps to find some useful information is to perform a google **(!)** search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com` in it. I found the above link searching for `site:tex.stackexchange.com use loop in animate`. The built-in search engine of this site is often (again according to what I find) less efficient. This leaves the question what to do with your question. We could close it as a duplicate or one of us writes an answer of the type "`animate` has its own means to do loops", what do you think?

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the tip. Usually I use just google search, works decently enough in most LaTeX problems I had. Funnily enough, I know of "site:" but somehow it never occurred to me to apply it to stackexchange. If there's any reputation to be earned by upvoted and accepted answer, it should go to you since you solved my issue, otherwise I'm fine with closing as duplicate.

Comment: @marmot Admittedly, now I'm kinda curious what exactly was breaking in the way I tried to do it, but it's purely, as they say, academic curiosity. I think I can live without finding out.

Comment: OK, then we leave the question open.

Answer (score 1):

Frame content is temporarily saved in TeX saveboxes, before being distilled into so-called PDF Form XObjects. In the code below, the `\newframe` and `animateinline` command and environment are replaced by LaTeX box saving commands, leading to the observed error during processing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\newcount\spiniter

\spiniter=1
\begin{lrbox}{0}
Text 0
\loop
  \end{lrbox}
  \begin{lrbox}{0}
  Text \the\spiniter
  \advance \spiniter by1
  \ifnum \spiniter<10
\repeat
\end{lrbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, the error does not occur, if a standard class is used, or if, in the case of `beamer`, the `frame` environment has been removed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}
\newcount\spiniter

\spiniter=1
\begin{lrbox}{0}
Text 0
\loop
  \end{lrbox}
  \begin{lrbox}{0}
  Text \the\spiniter
  \advance \spiniter by1
  \ifnum \spiniter<10
\repeat
\end{lrbox}

%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```